# Bootstrap carousel with asp repeater dynamically in SharePoint 2013

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint, repeater, carousel

So I have the code for my Bootstrap carousel that gets the images from my library in Visual Studio. Now I want this carousel to work dynamically by getting the images from a document library in SharePoint 2013 instead of from Visual Studio.

Standard code in Carousel.ascx

```
 <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel" data-ride="carousel">
 <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators" style="top:85%">
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner">
     <div class="item active" style="height:200px;">
        <a href="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/subsite/ %>" runat="server"><img src="../../_layouts/15/Project1/Images/carousel1.png"></a>
     </div>
     <div class="item" style="height:200px;">
        <a href="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/subsite/ %>" runat="server"><img src="../../_layouts/15/Project1/Images/carousel2.png"></a>
     </div>
     <div class="item " style="height:200px;">
        <a href="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/subsite/ %>" runat="server"><img src="../../_layouts/15/Project1/Images/carousel3.png"></a>
     </div>
     <div class="item " style="height:200px;">
        <a href="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/subsite/ %>" runat="server"><img src="../../_layouts/15/Project1/Images/carousel4.png"></a>
```

(Two ending div tags missing at the end) And this works perfectly. But now I'm trying with two repeaters (one for indicators and one for carousel inner)

New code in Carousel.ascx

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel" data-ride="carousel">

<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators" style="top:85%">
    <asp:Repeater ID="indicatorRepeater" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li class="<%# IndicatorClass(Container.ItemIndex)%>"></li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ol>

<div class="carousel-inner">
    <asp:Repeater ID="carouselRepeater" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="<%# CarouselClass(Container.ItemIndex)%>" style="height:200px;">
        <a href="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/subsite %>" runat="server"><img src="http://sp2013/Carousel/<%#Eval("LinkFilenameNoMenu")%>"></a>
    </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

(Last ending div tag missing)
Code behind, Carousel.ascx.cs

```
public partial class Carousel : UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb;

        SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Carousel");

        if (list != null)
        {
            SPListItemCollection collection = list.GetItems();

            if (collection.Count > 0)
            {
                DataTable table = collection.GetDataTable();
                carouselRepeater.DataSource = table;
                carouselRepeater.DataBind();
                indicatorRepeater.DataSource = table;
                indicatorRepeater.DataBind();
            }
        }

        carouselRepeater.ItemDataBound += carouselRepeater_ItemDataBound;
        indicatorRepeater.ItemDataBound += indicatorRepeater_ItemDataBound;
    }

    void carouselRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        string s = "";
    }

    void indicatorRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        string s = "";
    }

    public string CarouselClass(int itemIndex)
    {
        if (itemIndex == 0)
        {
            return "item-active";
        }
        else
        {
            return "item";
        }
    }

    public string IndicatorClass(int itemIndex)
    {
        if (itemIndex == 0)
        {
            return "active";
        }
        else
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when the carousel Changes to slide 2. The first one works perfect and the div have the class "item-active" while the indicator have the class "active". But in the next slide, I get the image, but then it is stuck. And the indicator does not get the active class. I've searched for this in different sites, and found this one http://devnet.kentico.com/forums/f65/fp21/t40584/bootstrap-carousel which is the only one I could find, but I don't know if it really helps me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are missing the data-target attribute on the carousel navigation li elements: data-target="#myCarousel".

Comment: Actually I've tried that Before, still the same result. I Think it has something to do with div class "item-Active" and "item" because when the carousel switch slide, it contains the class "item next left" and then "item Active". In my case, it contains "item next left" but won't continue...Thanks anyway!

Comment: Can you post the code on jsfiddle.net or on a similar service? The data-target is still needed to make the navigation work properly.

Comment: The carousel is working very fine without the data-target, but I've tried to use it in this new code and I still got the same error. Here is the code in .ascx: http://jsfiddle.net/6ECX6/ And the code behind: http://pastebin.com/mnYEidk9

Comment: The example code in the jsfiddle is from the ascx file, I would need to see the output and the html that it generates. Can you paste the full html output?

Comment: Well, you have this one: http://jsfiddle.net/QU7Mx/ But it take some time to load, because i just copied all the js and css from bootstrap and that is a lot of code! The output don't want to start in this case..but you can se how it looks like. And the code is WITHOUT the repeater, so this is my old code. I just switched images to a random from google

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you

```
 <div class='<%# Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? "item active" : "item" %>'>
```

From

http://forums.asp.net/t/1994608.aspx?Bootstrap+slider+using+repeater+control